# Scala how to build an associative List based on a list of Tuples

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, refactoring, tuples

I am trying to solve a problem: Write a function that will output the largest item association given an input of item association pairs.

Example input:

[[Item1, Item2],
[Item2, Item3],
[Item2, Item4],
[Item5, Item6]]

Output: [Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4]

I'm trying to solve it in a clean and functional style using Scala, this is my initial implementation:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val m = List[(String,String)]("item1" -> "item2", 
        "item2" -> "item3",
        "item2" -> "item4",
        "item5" -> "item6")

    val l: List[String] = getAssociationList(m)    
    l.foreach((s) => println(s))
  }

  def getAssociationList(l:List[(String,String)]) : List[String] = {    
    def f(k:String, l:List[(String,String)]) : List[String] = {
      var list:List[String] = List(k)
      l.filter((t:(String,String)) => t._1.equals(k)).foreach(
          {case (key, value) => list = list ++ f(value, l)}
      )
      return list
    }
    f(l(0)._1, l)
  }
}
```

It outputs the correct result but

I'm using  `var list:List[String] = List(k)` which clearly seems non-functional, is there a way to improve this function in order to make it more cleaner and better aligned with functional style best practices in Scala?

Comment: Can you explain the function more clearly? I'm having a difficult time understanding what 'largest item association' means - your example doesn't make sense. I see one output item per Tuple in the input, but there's no consistent relationship.

Comment: The problem is to build a list of Strings based on the list of Tuples (String,String) which first item of tuple contains the root of hierarchy "item1" it should be 1st in resulting list, item1 points to item2, so it comes second, item2 points to item3 and item4, so both item3 and item4 have the same "rank" item5 and item6 aren't pointed by any other item from the cascaded hierarchy originating from item1 so they're not part of the resulting list.

Comment: Okay I understand now - in that case it seems like you did the difficult part already (making the recursive algorithm). jwvh rewrote it in the 'functional' format (having immutability with no vars nor side effects and chaining functions on the list with the filter and flatMap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a more concise and functional way of doing the same thing.

```
def getAssociationList(l:List[(String,String)]) : List[String] = {
  def f(k:String) : List[String] =
    k :: l.filter(_._1 == k).flatMap(x => f(x._2))

  f(l.head._1)
}
```